# Adding in links for a new user

Tags: support

I've just attempted to fix the links in an answer posted by a new user:

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/58722/

I assume they can't post links because of the new user restrictions, so I edited their post to fix up the link markdown.

However, this seems to have just removed the links from the question? They are still present in the Markdown, but they do not appear in the rendered output. I assumed that my edit would allow the links to appear? Is this not the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only bit you missed off was the http:// so the parser was not seeing them as valid URLs and just ignored them.

I fixed them for you by adding the http:// back in.